# How to pass retrieved text to textfield Flutter

Tags: flutter, search, textfield, voice

I am using speech to text (speech_recognition ) plugin and retrieving text from voice but how can i put the text in to the search field (TextField) after retrieving text. So i want to retrieve data from voice and search it.
here is my code:

// Here is retrieved text inside container

```
  Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                (transcription.isEmpty)
                    ? "Speak to Record"
                    : "Your text is \n\n$transcription",
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

// Here is my SearchField (TextField)

```
   Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (text) {

                _con.refreshSearch(text);
              },
              onSubmitted: (text) {
                _con.saveSearch(text);
              },
              controller: _searchController,
              autofocus: true,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                hintText: S.of(context).search_for_product,
                hintStyle: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .caption
                    .merge(TextStyle(fontSize: 14)),
                prefixIcon:
                    Icon(Icons.search, color: Theme.of(context).accentColor),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.1))),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.3))),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.1))),
                suffixIcon: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: scanBarcode,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/img/barcode.png",
                        height: 20,
                        color: Colors.deepOrangeAccent,
                      ),
                    ),
                    _buildVoiceInput(
                      onPressed: _speechRecognitionAvailable && !_isListening
                          ? () => start()
                          : () => stop(),
                      label: _isListening ? S.of(context).listening : '',
                    ),

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the `transcription` value into consideration, which is responsible of having the text, what you can do is to make use of it, and change the data using `Search TextEditingController`.

So, here what I am taking about. I am not sure where are you fetching the data actually, but you can change the values, as soon as you get the data from the voice like this, and assign it to the Controller to fill the `Search Field`

```
// Suppose you are fetching the data from this method, 
void fetchTextFromVoice(){
   setState(() {
     // Here you might be assigning the value to the Transcript value
     this.transcription = data_from_voice;
     // also this does the magic, which will put the data inside the Search Field
     // Your TextEditingController is the key to do that
     _searchController.text = data_from_voice; 
     // or _searchController.text = transcription; Since transcript has some value
  });
}
```

Also, read about [TextEditingController Class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html) on what all are the operations you can perform using it. More knowledge to you on this Class will help you in great extent :)

I hope that helps, if not, then please show me where is the function where you are setting the value to `transcription`. You can assign the value to the same place, like above to `_searchController.text` and you are good to go. Let me know :)

Comment: Thank you soo much, it really helped me

Comment: Happy to help @Rock :)

Comment: Hello Sorry I have another question, If you can see inside text field. there is onChanged(){ } function  which is calling a function to search a query. What i mean when user is typing,  onChanged is triggering and searching for product but when i am putting my voice to text inside TextField and assigning it through _searchController the onChanged is not working unless i type once from keyboard. How can i make search working after transcription is assigned to the _searchController ? Thanks in advance !